# How to setup HWIOAuthBundle with FOSOAuthServerBundle

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

Trying to use both bundles with latest Symfony (V:2.7.2).

FOSOauth is set and works fine, but adding HWIOAuthBundle isn't so trivial. Following the instruction in native Read.me brought me to this:

- The service "hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils" has a dependency on a
  non-existent service "hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.api".

How to setup this two together?

Comment: Hello, have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't configured properly *oauth* section in the firewall (*security.yml* file) you want [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) to work with.
For example, with Facebook:

```
 // app/config/config.yml

 hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: main
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type: facebook
            ...
```

Then you need to configure *main* firewall

```
// app/config/security.yml

main:
    pattern:   ^/
    oauth:
        resource_owners:
            facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
        oauth_user_provider:
            service: my_custom_oauth_user_provider
    ...
```

Don't forget to declare facebook *login-check* route

```
// app/config/routing.yml

facebook_login:
    path: /login/check-facebook
```

and you also need to create a user provider (the bundle itself [has some built-in providers](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-configuring_the_security_layer.md) that you can extend and modify) and register it as a service

```
// app/config/services.yml

my_custom_oauth_user_provider:
    class: AppBundle\Security\OAuthUserProvider
```

As your question is how to setup HWIOAuthBundle with FOSOAuthServerBundle, there is a very complete guide of how to achieve this: [A way to integrate FosUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new firewall (e.g. secured_area) with authentication way "oauth".

For example:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                    google:             "/login/check-google"
                    my_custom_provider: "/login/check-custom"
                    my_github:          "/login/check-github"
                login_path:        /login
                use_forward:       false
                failure_path:      /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service
```

You can find this info [here](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-configuring_the_security_layer.md#b-configure-the-oauth-firewall)